# UPDATE FOR SELECT

Tags: php, mysql

There is a query

```
UPDATE users SET hash =: hash, num_try_incorrect_pass = 0 
WHERE email =: email; SELECT * FROM users WHERE email =: email
```

First perform UPDATE
Next SELECT

How to do this with one request?

Comment: These are two Queries you cant marge them

Comment: Maybe you are loking for `transactions`?

Comment: Make it into a stored procedure and call that using pdo or mysqli

Comment: Simple answer: call the two queries separately. But even if you could call them together, it definitely won't work as shown, because you can't use the same placeholder name twice in a single query.

Comment: I need to return an array, query once run

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using `stored procedures?` If you are looking for execute both queries from one code-statement you can define them as stored procedure in your database.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE ExecuteQueries(IN pEmail VARCHAR(50),
                    IN pHash VARCHAR(60))
  BEGIN
    UPDATE users SET hash=pHash, num_try_incorrect_pass = 0 WHERE email = pEmail;
    SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = pEmail;
  END //
DELIMITER ;
```

You can then execute both of these statements though your php code in this manner:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL ExecuteQueries($sEmail,$sHash)");
```

For more info: [Getting Started with MySQL Stored Procedures](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/getting-started-with-mysql-stored-procedures.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want.

You want to run a single query on your database to both update and select the updated row(s)? If so, this can't be done. You should consider creating a MySQL function to update and return a resultset with your latter query. [Here's the docs on how to create functions and procedures with MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html)